# Arrival and departure at Dubai international airport T3

Tags: transit, dubai, dxb, emirates

My mother is travelling alone and her arrival and departure terminal is T3 at Dubai international airport. I would like to know that after arriving at T3 which direction she will go for departure ? Is it on same floor or she needs to go down or up? She is travelling by Emirates on both and she will catch Dubai to Seattle, USA flight. Also is there any help desk counters there ?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, Terminal 3 at DXB is HUGE but it is a friendly place. Directions up/down/left/right changes based on which concourse and gate she arrives in. Even for frequent travellers, only way to navigate through the terminal after each arrival is to closely follow the signs or to ask Emirates/dnata(ground handling team) employees.

Once she enters the terminal, "Connections/Transfer Desks" are clearly marked as Red. Its almost impossible to miss them.

Refer to this image : 
[image]

Presuming that your mother can read basic English, navigation should not be a problem. In addition to it there are plenty of uniformed staff roaming around in the terminal and everyone will be happy to assist her.

If you are too concerned, please user [Marhaba Services Transfer facility](http://www.marhabaservices.com/english/our-services/meet-greet) available at AED 150 per pax.